# autocomplete ,autocorrect is not working in android 4.4 using cordova or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using `<input type='text' autocorrect='off' autocomplete='off' spellcheck='off' ng-model='xxx'></input>` but none of these are working in android 4.4(tested on moto g,moto e)

how can i disable this auto-check,predictions in javascript/jquery/angular?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... forgot the hyphen, it doesn't look like it's needed. Maybe in Android XML layouts, but not in HTML.

http://davidwalsh.name/disable-autocorrect

(Also I'm recommending you Google search, it found your answer in 10 seconds.)

Comment: no those are not applying on the fields on 4.4, I tested on nexus using 4.3 it is working fine but not on motoe or moto g or sony experia.